# Runnning bandit via tox in gitlab-runner does not behave correctly

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, tox

When I run `bandit` via `tox` in a `gitlab-runner` environment it behaves differently compared to if I run it via `tox` in my Ubuntu environment.

- *gitlab-runner environment* -> project source directory is recursively analyzed **but skippes files**
- *ubuntu environment* -> project source directory is recursively analyzed

The invocation when run in the *ubuntu environment* is: `tox -e bandit`

The invocation when run in the *gitlab-runner environment* is: `gitlab-runner exec docker bandit`

In case of the *gitlab-runner* environment the relevant message is (with `[source-root-directory]` as `src` root directory):

```
Files skipped (4):
    [source-root-directory]/__init__.py (syntax error while parsing AST from file)
    [source-root-directory]/[some-file].py (syntax error while parsing AST from file)
    [source-root-directory]/[some-other-file].py (syntax error while parsing AST from file)
    ...
```

The relevant excerpt from the `tox.ini` is (with `[source-root-directory]` as `src` root directory):

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py34

[testenv:bandit]
deps = {[testenv]deps}
commands = bandit {posargs:-r [source-dir]}
```

The relevant excerpt from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
bandit:
  stage: test
  image: python:latest
  script:
  - pip install tox
  - tox -e bandit
  allow_failure: true
```

Comment: Did you ask the gitlab-runner devs already what the problem could be?

Comment: Because I don't know if it relates to gitlab-ci (and not the integration of all tools involved) I did not so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the versions of the tools you're running and Python are the same in both environments. `python:latest` is currently using python 3.7 while Ubuntu is probably running 2.7

Comment: Thanks! Changing `image: python:latest` to `image: python:2.7` did the trick for now... I have to adjust the `tox.ini` with the `image:` still...